# targets - object not found, even though it's loadable

Tags: r, targets-r-package

I've been trying to debug this problem for a while now, but I'm unable to figure out why it's happening.

```
tar_plan(
  tar_target(
    rctd_seurat_object_file,
    here::here(config$datadir, "pdac_tempus_rctd.rds"),
    format = "file"
  ),
  rctd_seurat_object = readRDS(rctd_seurat_object_file),
  original_metadata = rctd_seurat_object@meta.data,

  # Save the updated Seurat object
  tar_target(
    pdac_tempus_file,
    update_seurat_object(
      rctd_seurat_object
      here::here(config$outdir, "pdac_tempus.rds")
    ),
    format = "file"
  ),
  pdac_tempus <- readRDS(pdac_tempus_file),
  # metadata <- pdac_tempus@meta.data
)
```

Here, for `rctd_seurat_object_file`, I'm pointing to a file, and loading that into `rctd_seurat_object`. I then use the `update_seurat_object` function to process and save the updated object into the path provided, and return the path to the output file from the function. That is saved in `pdac_tempus_file`. Now, when I try to call the `readRDS` on the `pdac_tempus_file`, just as I was doing before for `rctd_seurat_object`, it's throwing object `pdac_tempus_file` not found error.

I've tried loading that using `tar_load(pdac_tempus_file)` and it's being loaded successfully, and points to the correct output file. But I have no idea why it's not working in the above case.

Can anyone point me to some helpful documentation or guide me on how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: The code you’ve posted has a syntax error (probably a missing comma). To avoid this please always post the *actual* code as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

In order to help people help you, I would suggest to make sure to provide a reproducible example: see [recommendations for R related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/21085566).

That being said, it seems from your code that your issue is that you are mixing up two types of syntax to specify your `targets` workflow:

1. using `tar_plan()` that expects `stepB = do_something(stepA)`
2. using `tar_target()` that [expects a different organization](https://books.ropensci.org/targets/walkthrough.html#target-script-file).

The [{targets} user manual](https://books.ropensci.org/targets/) has extensive documentation and examples of good practices. Especially, the [External files example](https://books.ropensci.org/targets/data.html#external-files) is worth trying out with your case.

At the end of your file, you are accessing the RDS file like in standard R instead of using the `targets` approach (see `https://books.ropensci.org/targets/projects.html#sharing-targets`)

Best,